# compilation error when using java over HTTP Protocol in Load runner 12.01

Tags: loadrunner

i have recorded my application using java over HTTP protocol in Load Runner 12.01, however when i am compiling my script it is throwing an error like this

```
Notify: Found jdk version: 1.6.0.   [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
classpath=D:\LR12.01 Scripts\AirArabia\Scripts\Airarabia\Login_Logout\;c:\program files (x86)\hp\loadrunner\classes\srv;c:\program files (x86)\hp\loadrunner\classes;D:\Fanatic\Softwares\Jmeter\Jmeter2.11\apache-jmeter-2.11\lib\ext\onlyclass.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\lib\;;;;c:\program files (x86)\hp\loadrunner\lib\xstream-1.3.jar;c:\program files (x86)\hp\loadrunner\lib\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar  [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
Compilation process failed. [MsgId: MERR-22997]
<identifier> expected   [MsgId: MERR-22986]
    lr.output_message("abc");   [MsgId: MERR-22986]
                     ^  [MsgId: MERR-22986]
illegal start of type   [MsgId: MERR-22986]
    lr.output_message("abc");   [MsgId: MERR-22986]
                      ^ [MsgId: MERR-22986]
2 errors    [MsgId: MERR-22986]
```

can any one help it for me???

Answer (score 0):

You cant execute java code in web HTTP script.

you need to choose java related protocol and execute.